# Turing machine that accepts even length strings

Tags: discrete-mathematics, turing-machines

Can someone help me with some tips on how to create a turing machine that only accepts even length strings with an input alphabet of {0,1}?

Comment: Details will depend on the exact definition of TM. Rut roughly there are $2$ special stated, O and E. We keep moving right, and if we see a $0$ or a $1$, we change state. And if we bump into a B (blank) and are in State E, we halt.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you start from the leftmost 1. You need a "status bit" saying if the number of 1's counted so far is even/odd. In each step, change the status bit and move right until the symbol is 0.